# Ionic 5-Clear the searchbox text when clicking the reset button

Tags: ionic-framework, search, ionic5

I am working with ionic 5 ..I have a ionsearch to search the contents from a list.Then i have another reset button while pressing this reset button i want the ionsearch text typed inside the searchbar to be cleared.Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use its ionClear event to do whatever you want e.g Clear the text

```
(ionClear)="onClear($event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content of the `ion-searchbar` component through the `value` property:

```
document.querySelector('ion-searchbar').value = '';
```

This will also automatically call the `ionInput` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use [(ngModel)]="searchData" click on button call function and clear 'searchData'.

For eg. 
/** html code */
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search users" [debounce]="250" mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchData"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-button mode="ios" expand="block" color="carnation" (click)="clearSearch()">
          Clear
</ion-button>

/**
typescript code
*/
public searchData:string ='';

clearSearch(){
  this.searchData = '';
}
```